# Disable Interaction with screen till Payment is done

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Dears,

I have this screen where there are the purchasable product to choose from. I want the user not to be able to press on button of buying product and then presses again on another purchasable product while waiting for the server to respond.

To make it clear, I want the screen to be disabled till the payment is done or declined. The technical problem is that i can disable all the buttons when the presses on a purchasable product, but what i cant make is to enable all the buttons again when the user declines the payment. because the event happens in a totally different class than the view controller.

This is the screen:[image: This is the purchase screen]

When the user presses monthly, the yearly and life time should be disabled till the user either cancels the payment or approves it.

Again my question, The class that fires when the user completes the registration

[image]

and this is a payment observer called from another class which handles the payment completion

[image]

So How should i enable the buttons again !!

Please don't hesitate if you have any questions to ask

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't look like Swift to me. ;)

Comment: It is in ObjC. Anyways, to be more clear you have all three buttons from different class and showing it on on view?

Comment: You can add a view to the application's `keyWindow` with full screen size.

Or just simply use some third-party HUDs like: [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD), and [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Comment: @AAA All buttons are on the view controller class. The In app purchase is on a different class and even the completion listener is on a third class.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried this: On click of first button, set the UserInteractionEnabled as false for the other two buttons. and on completion listener, revert the user interaction as true for all buttons??

Comment: @AAA This is exactly my problem making UserInteractionEnabled to false is not a problem at all. The problem is reverting back the buttons when the completion is done. I don't have a reference to the ViewController from the Payment class

Comment: Okay. I can understand your problem, let me see what I can do. Will get back in 2-3 hours.

Comment: I tried the same with my code, it is working fine for me. If you, we can chat about this issue further in a chat room.